# Undefined property for custom class

Tags: javascript, class, prototype

Let's say I have classes `A` and `B`. Class `B` has a member which is an instance of class `A`, let's call it `this.a`.

When inside `B`'s methods I try to access `A`'s methods as `this.a.<methodName>`, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: this.a is undefined
```

Here is my code:

```
function A (name) {
  this.name = name;
}
A.prototype.foo = function () {
  this.name = this.name.toUpperCase();
};
A.prototype.bar = function () {
  this.name = this.name.toLowerCase();
};

function B () {
  this.a = new A('Hello, World!');
}
B.prototype.methodsOfA = {
  foo: this.a.foo, // here is the problem
  bar: this.a.bar  //
};
B.prototype.executeMethodOfA = function (methodName) {
  this.methodsOfA[methodName]();
  //the following works if I delete B.prototype.methodsOfA:
  //if (methodName.toLowerCase() === 'foo') this.a.foo();      
  //else if (methodName.toLowerCase() === 'bar') this.a.bar(); // 
};

b = new B();

console.log(b.a.name);
b.executeMethodOfA('foo');
console.log(b.a.name);
b.executeMethodOfA('bar');
console.log(b.a.name);
```

Instead, if I use the following definition:

```
B.prototype.methodsOfA = {
  foo: A.prototype.foo,
  bar: A.prototype.bar
};
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: this.name is undefined
```

(probably because `this` in this case is `b` and a `B` object has no `name` property.)

So, how can I access `this.a.<methodName>`  from inside `B`?

**Note:** This is a simplified version of a larger problem. I know that what I asked could be solved with class/prototype inheritance, but ideally I would like `B` **not** to inherit from `A`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My spidey sense says there's a better way to solve this problem, but here is some working code for now..

```
function A (name) {
    this.name = name;
}
A.prototype.foo = function () {
    this.name = this.name.toUpperCase();
};
A.prototype.bar = function () {
    this.name = this.name.toLowerCase();
};

function B () {
    this.a = new A('Hello, World!');
}
B.prototype.methodsOfA = function (methodName) {
  var methods = {
    foo: this.a.foo.bind(this.a),
    bar: this.a.bar.bind(this.a),
  }
  return methods[methodName];
};
B.prototype.executeMethodOfA = function (methodName) {
    this.methodsOfA(methodName)();
};
b = new B();

console.log(b.a.name);
b.executeMethodOfA('foo');
console.log(b.a.name);
b.executeMethodOfA('bar');
console.log(b.a.name);
```

You had two problems:

- `this` in the context of an object didn't refer to the `this` you were thinking of. It was referring to the window, because `methodsOfA`, as a plain object, won't be injected with `this`. I changed it to a proper method, and now `this` is the `this` you want.
- You need to bind the A methods to your local instance of A itself. This is because methods are only given the expected `this` pointer when invoked in the style `a.foo()`. Assigning `a.foo` to another name and invoking it, as you're doing, will lose the `this` context. You can force the correct context with `bind()` as you see above.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Indeed, I was confused about what `this` referred to :)

Answer (score 1):

1. The way you referning `this` is wrong. In your case `this` refers to the global context i.e) `window`.
2. you can simply use `Object.create(A.prototype)` to simply get all methods of A.
3. while executing `this.methodsOfA[methodName]()` - it calls the `A`'s method with `B`'s context. So, there is no property called `name` in your `B` context - it fail.
4. you have to call `A`'s method with the context of `A` which is stored in `B`'s context i.e) `this.a`

   `this.methodsOfA[methodName].call(this.a);`

```js
function A (name) {
  this.name = name;
}
A.prototype.foo = function () {
  this.name = this.name.toUpperCase();
};
A.prototype.bar = function () {
  this.name = this.name.toLowerCase();
};

function B () {
  this.a = new A('Hello, World!');
}
B.prototype.methodsOfA = Object.create(A.prototype);
B.prototype.executeMethodOfA = function (methodName) {
  this.methodsOfA[methodName].call(this.a);
};

b = new B();

console.log(b.a.name);
b.executeMethodOfA('foo');
console.log(b.a.name);
b.executeMethodOfA('bar');
console.log(b.a.name);
```